# Clojure doseq nested loops to make new set

Tags: loops, clojure

In Clojure, I want to be able to multiply all numbers in a set and add them all to a new set to return.

```
=>(multiply-all #{ 1 2 3})

#{1 4 6 3 2 9}
```

Here's my implementation:

```
(defn multiply-all [num-set]
  (loop [new-set num-set
         cur-set num-set]
       (if (= 0 (count cur-set))  new-set
       (recur (into new-set (map #(* (first cur-set) %) num-set)) (rest cur-set)))))
```

Is there a way to do this using doseq WITHOUT using transients.  Something like this:

```
(let [s #{ 1 2 3}]
 (doseq [outer s]
   (doseq [inner s]
     (let [multiplied (* outer inner)]
      (println (conj s multiplied))
      ))))
```

I'm interested in any suggestions for a cleaner way to do this.

---EDIT----
Here's another way using reduce:

```
(defn multiply-all2 [num-set]
  (let [step (fn [[ result ] mult]
           [(into result (map #(* mult %) num-set))])]
    (first (reduce step [num-set] num-set))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`doseq`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq) is for side effects. You probably want to use [`for`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for) instead:

```
user=> (set (for [a #{1 2 3} 
                  b #{1 2 3}] 
              (* a b)))
#{1 4 6 3 2 9}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn multiply-all [s]
  (set (mapcat #(map * s (repeat %)) s)))
```

Comment: Very cool.  The other solution using 'for' is probably easier for newbies, but it's good to know this option.